# Postgresql problem during setup of Mayan EDMS

Tags: postgresql, mayanedms

I am very excited to install Mayan EDMS as it looks very promising. However, I am not an expert. I tried to follow the guidelines at https://docs.mayan-edms.com/chapters/deploying.html and use a chroot on my NAS. So far most of it run smoothly and I could even solve a few problems by my own.

But now I arrived at step 9 in order to initialize the project.
I should adjust the command

```
MAYAN_MEDIA_ROOT=/opt/mayan-edms/media \
/opt/mayan-edms/bin/mayan-edms.py initialsetup
```

So I did. But it results in

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "mayan", database "mayan"
```

As I have no clue about postgresql I googled it and found my pg_hba.conf in /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
In it the config says:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# test for mayan
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

I do not know why these entries are not sufficient. Can you please help with some advice?
Thanks!

Full disclosure: I also asked this on the Mayan-EDMS-board, but I guess that it won't hurt to ask you guys, too :)

Comment: Put the last line at the beginning of the file and  reload PostgreSQL config

Comment: Hmm, the error doesn't really match the contents of your `pg_hba.conf`. Can you log in through `psql` on the command line?

Comment: Perhaps he/she forget to reload postgresql config

Comment: Unfortunately I just oversaw one line and that led me to believe that the problem was solved. However, even with the changed order of lines the problem still exists. :(

Answer (score 0):

change
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
to
host    all             all             all               md5